# How to get unit vectors using `quiver()` in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to wrap my head around the `quiver` function to plot vector fields. Here's a test case:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X, Y = np.mgrid[1:1.5:0.5, 1:1.5:0.5]
print(X)
print(Y)
u = np.ones_like(X)
v = np.zeros_like(Y)
plt.quiver(X,Y, u, v)
plt.axis([0, 3, 0, 3], units='xy', scale=1.)
plt.show()
```

I am trying to get a vector of length 1, point from `(1,0)` to `(2,0)`, but here is what I get:

[image]

I have tried adding the `scale='xy'` option, but the behaviour doesn't change. So how does this work?

Answer (score 2):

First funny mistake is that you put the `quiver` arguments to the `axis` call. ;-)

Next, looking at [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html?highlight=matplotlib%20axes%20axes%20quiver#matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver), it says

> If `scale_units` is ‘x’ then the vector will be 0.5 x-axis units. To plot vectors in the x-y plane, with u and v having the same units as x and y, use `angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1.`

So let's do as the documentation tells us,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X, Y = np.mgrid[1:1.5:0.5, 1:1.5:0.5]

u = np.ones_like(X)
v = np.zeros_like(Y)
plt.quiver(X,Y, u, v, units='xy', angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1.)
plt.axis([0, 3, 0, 3])
plt.show()
```

and indeed we get a one unit long arrow:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks better, but doesn't seem to generalize if I change the vector to `u = np.ones_like(X)`, `v = np.ones_like(Y)`, I get a vector from `(1,1)` to `(2,2)`, which is not of length `1`. How do I get that to scale to have length `1`?

Comment: ähm?! a vector of length 1 in x and length 1 in y direction is sqrt(2) long. So why should it be 1 unit long?

Comment: I would like it to keep that same direction, but be scaled to length `1`.

Comment: A vector can be [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) by dividing by its norm. Do you need help doing that?