# Plot vector subtraction in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to plot three vectors, `b`, `d`, and `d-b`. Of course, this means that the tail of `d-b` touches the head of `b`. I'm using [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281966/) to plot arrows. However, I clearly don't understand the API, since the figure I get is baffling. The arrows look roughly like they're in the right directions, but the magnitudes are way off. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


b = np.array([4, 1])
d = np.array([-3, 3])
m = d-b

o = np.array([
    [0, 0, b[0]],
    [0, 0, b[1]]
])
v = np.array([
    [b[0], b[1]],
    [d[0], d[1]],
    [m[0], m[1]]
])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.quiver(*o, v[:, 0], v[:, 1])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646094/how-to-get-unit-vectors-using-quiver-in-matplotlib) and the matplotlib documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html), you need to use `angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1` to get the right units.

See code below:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


b = np.array([4, 1])
d = np.array([-3, 3])
m = d-b
print(np.linalg.norm(d))
o = np.array([
    [0, 0, b[0]],
    [0, 0, b[1]]
])
v = np.array([
    [b[0], b[1]],
    [d[0], d[1]],
    [m[0], m[1]]
])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.quiver(*o, v[:, 0], v[:, 1],angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
ax.set_xlim([-4,4])
ax.set_ylim([-4,4])
plt.show()
```

And the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's more convenient to store coordinates of vectors like so:

```
S = np.stack([*o, v[:, 0], v[:, 1]])
>>> S
array([[ 0,  0,  4],
       [ 0,  0,  1],
       [ 4, -3, -7],
       [ 1,  3,  2]])
```

Now you can access coords of starting points and directions in this way:

```
>>> S[:2], S[2:]
(array([[0, 0, 4],
        [0, 0, 1]]),
 array([[ 4, -3, -7],
        [ 1,  3,  2]]))
```

As well as coords of ending points:

```
>>> S[:2] + S[2:]
array([[ 4, -3, -3],
       [ 1,  3,  3]])
```

So you can get all the points on a plane:

```
>>> pts = np.hstack([S[:2], S[:2] + S[2:]])
array([[ 0,  0,  4,  4, -3, -3],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  3,  3]])
```

For later part, look into an answer of `jylls` and use:

```
plt.quiver(*S, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
```

Finally, as you've got a nice plot, you might be interested how to specify boundaries for your plot. You can do it like so:

```
x_min, y_min = np.min(pts, axis=1)
x_max, y_max = np.max(pts, axis=1)
plt.xlim([x_min, x_max])
plt.ylim([y_min, y_max])
plt.show()
```

[image]